# Hide everything except image in an element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html code, and I need to hide the "BY" word and the "USERNAME" and show only the "AVATAR" of the user.

I need to make it with CSS only, but I cannot find the right selector to make it.

Is it even possible? Thanks!

```html
<div class="entry-meta">
  <span class="byline">by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n"
       href="path-to-username-profile" title=
       "View all Downloads by username">username <img alt="" class="avatar"
        height="50" src= "path-to-jpg.jpg" width="50"></a></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.entry-meta {  font-size: 0;  }
```

Comment: I am using theme and the html is generated by some php file which I didnt found... .entry-meta { font-size: 0 !important;  } did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the parent element and show the child.  Closest you can do in your case is hide the byline with display:none and the try to hide the text of the username anchor with:

```
font-size: 0; color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set font-size to 0 of your main div and bigger font-size of inner div

```
.entry-meta .byline{
  font-size:0;
}
.entry-meta .author.vcard{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
.entry-meta *{
visibility:hidden;
}
.entry-meta .avatar{
visibility:visible;
}
```

This will hide all elements within the div except for the img tag.